# Format any number in Indian currency style using C language

Tags: c

Indian Currency format is 12345 → "12,345" (for odd length) and 123456 → "1,23,456" (for even length). I have included all possibilities such as

**1. Minus sign: "-12,345"**.

**2. Decimal Point: "-12,345.345" or "12,345.123"**.

**3. Zero Condition 000000.123 → "0.123"**.

**4.Minus and Zero Condition '-000000.123' -> "-0.123"**

```
int  currencyFormatter(char av_currency[], int av_strLen, char *ap_formattedNumber)
        {
            char    flag = 'N';             //Taking a Flag to know whether thier is a decimal Point in Currency or not
            int     lengthOf = 0, index = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
            char    *decAr = NULL;
            char    *tmpCurrency = NULL;//Taking two Pointers one for Array with Commas(tmpCurrency) and decAr pointer for decimal Point array
            char    *s = NULL;

            s = strstr(av_currency, ".");//Checking for decimal Point in array

            if (s > 0)
            {
                flag    = 'D';                  // Changing Flag to show Decimal Point is Present in Array
                s       = strchr(av_currency, '.');
                index   = s - av_currency;          //Index at which Decimal Point is present
                av_strLen   = strlen(av_currency) - index;      // calculated formula to know length of an  array needed to contain decimal point and Numbers after that 
                decAr   = (char*)malloc(av_strLen*sizeof(char*));//allocated Memory using malloc
                decAr[av_strLen] = '\0';
                memmove(decAr, &av_currency[index], av_strLen); //memmove from decimal till end of array.
                av_currency[index] = '\0';

                if (!decAr)//Handled Null Condition for Pointer
                {
                    return -1;//All errors for Negative Number
                }
            }


            lengthOf    = strlen(av_currency) + (strlen(av_currency) / 2); // Derived Formula(It Works for Indian Currency Format) to know the length of an array is needed to contain numbers and Commas Together.
            tmpCurrency = (char*)malloc(lengthOf*sizeof(char*));
            strrev(av_currency);   //Reversed Array as commas comes at multiple of 3. eg=12345 reverse=54321 wdComma=543,21 index is 3 if number would had been bigger commas would had come at 3,6.
            while (av_currency[i] != '\0')
            {
                if (j % 3 == 0 && j >= 3 && av_currency[i] != '-')//all Commas come at multiple of 3 when you reverse an amount
                {
                    tmpCurrency[j] = ',';//If an , is found Increment only J as 
  is used as index number to store in tmpcurrency
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
                tmpCurrency[j] = av_currency[i];//storing the Value in tmpCurrency
                i++;//Incrementing 

                j++;//Incrementing
            }
            tmpCurrency[j] = '\0';//Null Condition

            if (!tmpCurrency)    // Checking for NULL Pointer
            {
                return -2;    //all errors for Negative value
            }

            flag == 'D' ? strcpy(av_currency, (strcat(strrev(tmpCurrency), decAr))) : strcpy(av_currency, (strrev(tmpCurrency)));//Ternary Operator

            strcpy(ap_formattedNumber,av_currency);//Copying formated number into original array
            free(tmpCurrency);//Releasing the memory
            free(decAr);//Releasing the Memory
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: **I** am getting a problem reading this mess. How about reading [ask] before posting and properly formatting the code.

Comment: That's the least of your problems. How about you look at your own post that you just posted. If you think it looks like a complete mess, then edit it and fix the formatting.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what is your problem and what your code does?

Comment: i have taken numbers in char array reversed it so in Indian Currency it is 3,2,2 format so by reversing what you will notice it that comma comes at multiple of 3 index.My Problem when try to put negative Sign and strrev my answer what i get is -,123,12,3 like this

Comment: "only using C functions" is unclear.  All compliant C code only using "C functions".  Where is `strrev(arr);` defined?  It is not part of the language nor part of the standard C library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Ask] page soon.  The information in your "I have taken numbers" comment should be added to the question, not comments.  You should show how the code in a function.  You should make an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You should show some sample inputs and the corresponding desired outputs.  Am I right in thinking that a value like 999999 should be printed as 9,99,999, and 87654321 like 8,76,54,321?  You should use similar examples in your question — many people here are not familiar with the intricacies of Indian currency formatting (though equally, many are).

Comment: Yes Jonathan i have made all the changes and Posted my answer and this it is clear. Thank You for your help. I hope Hold on this Question will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for above question.
Please try this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *printComma(double input_number,char *demo,char ap_it[],char ap_type[])
{
    char    *result = NULL;
    char    *lp_decimal_number = NULL;
    char    *main_number = NULL;
    char    *decimal_pos = NULL;
    char    zero[1] = {0};
    int     i = 0;
    int     j = 0;
    int     z = 0;
    int     cnt = 0;
    int     decimal_index = 0;
    int     lp_decimal_numberLen = 0 ;
    int     flag_dec = 0;
    int     flag_minus = 0 ;
    int     length_main;
    int     k = 0;
    int     length_demo=0;
    sprintf(demo,"%lf",input_number);
    if(strcmp(ap_type,"P") == 0)
       {
              if(strcmp(ap_it,"A") == 0 || strcmp(ap_it,"B") == 0)
              {
                     sprintf_s(demo,40,"%0.4lf",input_number);
              }
              else
              {
                     sprintf_s(demo,40,"%0.2lf",input_number);
              }
       }
       else
       {
              sprintf_s(demo,40,"%.0lf",input_number);
       }
    length_demo = strlen(demo); // finds the length of original string
    result = (char *)malloc((length_demo+10)*sizeof(char));
    main_number = (char *)malloc((length_demo+50)*sizeof(char));
    z = strspn(demo[0] == '-' ? (demo + 1) : demo , "0");
    if(z != 0)
    {
        if(demo[0] != '-')
        {
            memcpy(main_number,&demo[z],length_demo);
            main_number[length_demo]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
            puts(main_number);
            main_number[length_demo]='\0';
            flag_minus=1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(main_number,&demo[0],length_demo);
        main_number[length_demo]='\0';
    }
    length_main=strlen(main_number);
    decimal_pos = strstr(main_number,".");
    if(decimal_pos > 0)
    {
        decimal_index = decimal_pos - main_number ;  // Getting postion of decimal
        lp_decimal_numberLen = length_main - decimal_index; // Calculating the endpoint for decimal number
        if(length_main > 3) //Copying the decimal part to a separate array
        { 
            lp_decimal_number = (char *) malloc(lp_decimal_numberLen+1);
            memcpy( lp_decimal_number, &main_number[decimal_index], lp_decimal_numberLen );
            lp_decimal_number[lp_decimal_numberLen] = '\0';
            flag_dec=1;
            main_number[decimal_index]='\0';
        }
    }
    //logic for comma starts here
    strrev(main_number);
    i = 0;
    while(main_number[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (j%3 == 0 && j>=3 && main_number[i]!='-' && main_number[i]!='$')
        {
            result[j] = ',';
            cnt++;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        else if(cnt==1 || cnt==2)
        {
            result[j] = main_number[i];
        }
        else
        {
            result[j] = main_number[i];
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    result[j] = '\0';
    if(flag_dec==0)
    {
        if(flag_minus==0)
            return(strrev(result));
        else
        {
            strcat(result,"-");
            return(strrev(result));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(flag_minus==0)
            return(strcat(strrev(result),lp_decimal_number));
        else
        {
            strcat(result,"-");
            return(strcat(strrev(result),lp_decimal_number));
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    double  number;
    char    num[25] = {0};
    char    it_type[] = "A";
    char    ap_type[] = "P";
    char    *formattedNumber = NULL;
    printf("\n Enter the number n: ");
    scanf("%lf",&number);
    formattedNumber=printComma(number,num,it_type,ap_type);
    printf("\n Final Result = %s ",formattedNumber);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your code their is Count for which is used so that data is not lost during copying data from one array to another but maintaining count is not a good a idea because as the number increases you will  have to write (cnt==1 || cnt==2|| cnt==3|| cnt==4......) so on.You can if..else statement using ternary operator.

Comment: @Devious Ya i considered that count variable scenario but it wont harm anything because pratically count value is more than enough upto 8 or 10.Pratically count more than that is not taken into consideration.
about if else,ya there can be alternative using ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Do only positive values with your function!

Check if the value is negative before calling the function; call the function with the positive value; if it was negative to start with, add the minus sign afterwards.

```
int needssign = 0;
if (val < 0) needssign = 1;
indianformat(res, abs(val));
if (needssign) sprintf(res, "-%s", res);
```

Or make your current function a helper function and use the code above for the new improved function for formatting in Indian format.

Comment: Corner case: this is a problem with `val == INT_MIN` as `abs(INT_MIN)` is typically UB.

Comment: Thank You for the Help.What I have done is I have checked whether it is a Minus sign or not and added Comma.Previously my Number used to Get 
-,23,123. So now it will only Put comma by checking first in currency[i]!='-'.